# How to disable volume control in react-player

Tags: reactjs, typescript, volume, react-player

I want to use React Player and I do not need the volume, but I can not remove the volume button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop `muted` explained

https://github.com/CookPete/react-player

Comment: I want to remove the button, not to mute the video

Comment: my bad, you can try with controls props, or targeting controls element with pointer-events: none;

Answer (score 0):

Just add the controls={false} or remove this prop.

eg-

```
<ReactPlayer
      url='url'
      loop={true}
      playing={true}
      playsInline
      light={false}
      width='100%'
      height='100%'
      controls={false}
       />
```